# UI Layout and Elements in XML

Tags: java, xml, user-interface

I want to use XML for UI layout and element definition. Want them to be rendered as HTML.
Request to suggest a open source package for this.

Comment: Err… XHTML 1.0 Transitional? (eugh).

Comment: I think you can either have layout files in xml which will be rendered to html OR you can have jsp files whihc will be rendered. Or what is your usecase? Why you need both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean with 'Then that needs to be rendered using JSP.' as I mentioned in the comment.

If you want to use xml for UI layout take a look at:

http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-user-interface-toolkits

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Saxon or Xalan. Google for those.